# kolla ansible - missing sudo password

Tags: ansible, openstack, kolla-ansible

I try to precheck kolla-ansible before deploy openstack but here is the problem and I don't know how to fix it. I followed this document to setup :
https://github.com/hocchudong/ghichep-OpenStack/blob/master/13-Kolla/kolla-ansible/Kolla-Ansible-Docker.md
Can anyone help?[image]

UPDATE:
I fixed the missing sudo error by installing sshpass on controller and run this command on each node `echo "user_name ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/user_name`
When I prechecked, everything was fine, so I decided to deploy

```
kolla-ansible -i multinode deploy
```

And here is the problem
[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Very hard to read on an ipad, for example. Also, it's not a good idea to follow four years old instructions for an OpenStack version that has been obsolete for a while. Use https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html instead. In any case, could it be that you have not configured password-less sudo for your user account?

Comment: Sorry, i am using VMRC client on vSphere and I don't have permission to enable copy & paste between VMRC client and Windows/Linux Virtual Machine. I also follow docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html but it does not say anything about configuring password-less sudo

Comment: It's a requirement of Ansible. Think about it: How else can you perform tasks that require root privileges? Alternatively, you can provide the password as shown in the sample inventory at https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html#inventory.

Comment: Thanks sir, i installed sshpass on my controller and it fixed my problem, but now there is another issue, I've updated it on the post

Comment: Here is where I say I stop reading. My eyes hurt from the blurry red on black, even on a PC. Log on to the Kolla with ssh and replace the image with text. I did see the word "wallaby" - you seem to be using Mitaka instructions for Wallaby. It's very likely that you will run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable using insecure docker registry in globals.yml file in order to get past the

> ensure fluentd image is present for label check
> error.

```
################
# Docker options
################

# Custom docker registry settings:
#docker_registry
# Please read the docs carefully before applying docker_registry_insecure.
```

> docker_registry_insecure: "yes"

```
#docker_registry_username:
# docker_registry_password is set in the passwords.yml file.
```